# how to set time duration limit in custom wheel time picker android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using custom wheel time picker I want to set start time of the day in timepicker and End time of the day in timepicker

```
''''private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    _timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            context,
            AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,
            onTimeSetListener,
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            is24r);
    _timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm");
    _timePickerDialog.show();
}''''
```

''''    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
txtsetremindme.setText("before :Not Set");

```
        int hours = hourOfDay;
        int minutes = minute;
        alarmhour = hourOfDay;
        alarmminutes = minutes;
        String am_pm = "";
        //To get the AM/PM value set by user
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            am_pm = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            am_pm = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12) {
            am_pm = "PM";
        } else {
            am_pm = "AM";
        }

        String min = "";
        if (minutes < 10)
            min = "0" + minutes;
        else
            min = String.valueOf(minutes);
        String hrs = "";
        if (hours < 10)
            hrs = "0" + hours;
        else
            hrs = String.valueOf(hours);

        // Append in a StringBuilder to show setTime at the time of alarm ring
        setTime = new StringBuilder().append(hrs).append(":")
                .append(min).append(" ").append(am_pm).toString();
        AMPM = am_pm.toString();

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
        try {
            Selectedtime = format.parse(setTime);
            setDimensions(cardsetrepeat, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
            setDimensions(cardsetremindmebefore, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        Settime.setText(setTime);
        //Getting the time difference of current time and time set by user
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) { //If time set by user is already passed, set it for next day
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    }
};''''
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting.

Comment: (A) What exactly is your question? (B) Post only the *minimum* of code needed to show your issue.

Comment: FYI, The terrible `Calendar` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. These are bundled with later Android. For earlier Android, the latest tooling brings most of the *java.time* functionality via "API desugaring".